# Plotting a column-wise bee-swarm plot in Python

Tags: python, graph, seaborn, swarmplot

I have a sample dataset:

```
A   B   C
23  45  3
53  78  46
23  68  24
52  68  57
52  79  76
78  79  13
```

I want to plot a bee-swarm plot in which each column represents on swarm/section. Like:
[image]

How can I achieve this? I tried this:

```
sns.swarmplot(y=A)
```

But it only gives the swarmplot of 1 attribute and contains no label for the group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you should try to get your DataFrame into a "long" format. You can do this with [`DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html).

This will give you a dataframe like

```
   variable  value
0         A     23
1         A     53
2         A     23
3         A     52
4         A     52
5         A     78
6         B     45
7         B     78
8         B     68
9         B     68
10        B     79
11        B     79
12        C      3
13        C     46
14        C     24
15        C     57
16        C     76
17        C     13
```

Then you can plot it with Seaborn like so

```
sns.swarmplot(x="variable", y="value", data=df.melt())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataset = {
    'A': [23,53,23,52,52,78],
    'B': [45,78,68,68,79,79],
    'C': [3,46,24,57,76,13]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(dataset)

sns.swarmplot(x="variable", y="value", data=df.melt())
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Note that seaborn also accepts the wide form. So, here `sns.swarmplot(data=df)` (or  `sns.swarmplot(data=df[['A','B','C']])` to select part of the columns) would also work. Wide form is quite limited though, for example it doesn't support hue.